# How to get XML received from client on an ASMX Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx, webmethod

I have a Web Service (ASMX) and I would like my code to access the raw XML from the web service. How do I do that?

```
[WebMethod]
public sendAttachmentResponse sendAttachments(sendAttachmentRequest request)
{

   /***********************************************************/
  // somewhere around here  I would like to be able to get the XML that was actually sent 
  // by the client, not the serialization of the "request" parameter
  /************************************************************/

  var response = new sendAttachmentResponse ();
  response.header = new responseHeader();
  try
  {
    using(var repo = new DB())
    {
      repo.SendAttachmentsRequest(request);
    }
    response.header.status = "OK";
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    response.header.status = "KO";
    response.header.errorCode = ex.HResult.ToString();
    response.header.errorDescription = ex.Message;
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question? I'm currently in need of needing an answer to this as well.

Comment: @creatio I did not find a solution and I have moved on. For me it was only needed during testing phase, and it seemed strange that the system I was communicating with could get the exact message I was sending(they use some java I guess), but I have not been able to get their XML. Sorry I could not help you. Good luck.